# Visual Studio 2017 - Add Reference Tab not giving any options

Tags: visual-c++

I am pretty new to Visual Studio. I was trying to import "System.ServiceProcess" but couldn't and even when i tried adding a reference to its dll file, I was not able to find it in the AddReferences tab.
Really sorry if this is a dumb question.

P.S. Its a C++ project.

Pic showing the error:[image]

Comment: `System.ServiceProcess` is for a C# program. You can't add a .NET assembly to a Visual C++ program. They are two very different things. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: My aim was to create and start a service using c++ code when I came across this method. Please do let me know if there is any other easy way.

Answer (score 0):

The process for calling .NET code from C++ is outlined at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/828736/how-to-call-a-managed-dll-from-native-visual-c-code-in-visual-studio-n. Though being quite old, the documentation still applies:

- Create a COM visible .NET assembly
- Use regasm.exe (from within the developer command prompt) to export a type library and register the .NET assembly as a COM server (the latter step has to be repeated on all machines that run your program)
- Import the type library using an #import in your C++ code

However I advise against using System.ServiceProcess.dll directly and to create a .NET wrapper assembly instead. That way your registration is not broken by a .NET framework update and you can simplify the interface for your C++ code.